# While creating React Native app: Unknown Syntax Error: Unsupported option name ("--ignore-optional")

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**npm install -g create-react-native-app@1.0.0** was successfully added.

> create-react-native-app AppName

The error occurs while running the above command.

```
Unknown Syntax Error: Unsupported option name ("--ignore-optional"). 
$ yarn add [--json] [-E,--exact] [-T,--tilde] [-C,--caret] [-D,--dev] [-P,--peer] [-O,--optional] [--prefer-dev] [-i,--interactive] [--cached] ... 
`yarnpkg add --dev --exact --ignore-optional react-native-scripts` failed
```

Note: yarn -v
2.1.1

Comment: I added `npm install create-react-native-app@1.0.0` to my current working directory. Now trying to install app `create-react-native-app AppName` encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `npx create-react-native-app "AppName"` not `npm`

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that the folder name of the location you are installing is correct. For example you should use "ReactNative" instead of "React Native".
Best Regards

Comment: The folder name should not matter when installing with `-g`, and `create-react-app` can run in any folder as well